# Command Prompt error since i am using a generic path to open an excel file

Tags: ruby, win32ole

Command Prompt its not working since i am using a generic path to open a excel file. Here is the error message:

> T:\PointOfSale\Projects\Automated Testing\TASWeb\TP\TP_Branch>ruby -rubygems Tes
>   tTP_UK.rb
>   TestTP_UK.rb:19:in 'method_missing': (in OLE method `Open': )(WIN32OLERuntimeEr
>   ror)
>       OLE error code:800A03EC in Microsoft Excel
>         './../../../MasterFile.xls' could not be found. Check the spelling of the
>   file name, and verify that the file location is correct.
>
> If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, m
>   ake sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.
>       HRESULT error code:0x80020009
>         Exception occurred.
>           from TestTP_UK.rb:19:in `'
>   enter code here'

Generic path code

```
excel = WIN32OLE::new("excel.Application")
path = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../../MasterFile.xls"
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(path)
worksheet = workbook.WorkSheets(1) # Get first workbook
site = worksheet.Range('A2').Value # Get the value at cell in worksheet.
workbook.Close
excel.Quit
```

Any Ideas

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use an absolute path rather than a relative path when opening the file:

```
path = File.expand_path("../../../../MasterFile.xls", __FILE__)
```

Note that you will also need an additional '..' when using expand_path, since the first '..' is going back from the file.